# Using SHA 1 Hash in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cryptographic-hash-function

I want to hash some strings of character using sha1 in laravel. but no matter what the strings are, they are all returning the same hash. Please, i need to know why it is so, or what am i doing wrong . See below my code:

```
$lice = $serial->sname.$serial->company.$serial->effDate.$serial->ltype;
        //$serial->sname is MTS;
        //$serial->company is Godowns Technology;
        //$serial->effDate is 2017-01-24;
        //$serial->ltype is Trial

        $lice2= sha1($lice);
        $lice3 = chunk_split($lice2,5,'-');
        $lice4 =strtoupper($lice3);
  based on the information above, the $lice4 is always return: 
DA39A-3EE5E-6B4B0-D3255-BFEF9-56018-90AFD-80709
```

Please, i need assitance on this

Comment: The first assumption to challenge is that `$lice` is being set correctly. If the hash result is always the same, the overwhelming most likely scenario is that the value being hashed is always the same.

Comment: That is the sha1-hash for an empty string.

Comment: @Dilaz: does it mean that the variables are not fetched? that is why it is hashing empty string

Comment: and don't forget: **hashing** is not **encrypting**.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: I don't know who downvoted this question. if I know the answer, i wouldn't have posted this. So, why downvoting?. Why i wanted this is to create something like Product Key that has a definite number of characters

Comment: @Dilaz: thank you so much, this hint gave me a clue to what the issue is: I was using another thing ie the $serial-sname instead of $request->sname. the $request variable is what I should have used. Hence, all the concatenated variables are empty string.

Answer (score 0):

All, i did was to ensure that the my varibales were fetched from the form and they were properly targeted. Hence, once this was done, i could concatenate and get the correct hash.

```
 $lice = $request->sname.$request->company.$request->effDate;
        //$lice = $serial->sname;
        $lice2= sha1($lice);
        $lice3 = chunk_split($lice2,5,'-');
        $lice4 =strtoupper($lice3);

       Serial::create([
        'sname' => $request->sname,
        'company' => $request->company,
        'effDate' => $request->effDate,
        'ltype' => $request->ltype
        ]);
```